# How to swap Y and Z axis on export to Collada

Tags: export, collada

I'm using Blender as a modeling app and I need to export its data to Collada format for being consumed by a game engine. The thing is that Blender uses Z-axis to be the up-axis and the game engine uses Y as the up-axis.

I haven't found any option to swap the axis on Collada export dialog but I did find the option in almost every other export option. Is there a plugin out-there or other solution to add this option to the Collada export menu?

PS: I know that rotating through X-axis is achieved the same effect but its annoying to do it every single time I need to export, so I don't want to do that. Instead, propose another solution, if there is any.

[image: Example of wanted option]
[image]

Comment: AFAIK, The only way to do this in blender at the moment is rotating, as you mentioned. You could use an external tool such as [Collada Refinery](https://collada.org/mediawiki/index.php/COLLADA_Refinery), but that might even more inconvenient then just rotating in blender.

Answer (score 5):

*No*. Blender's Collada exporter does not have a convenient way to do this. Your best option is to rotate the object as you mentioned.

Note that just rotating the object might be insufficient for some applications, e.g those which actually care about Collada's up-axis specification (which can be either `Z_UP` or `Y_UP`).

If you're working with one of those, you'll also need to manually edit the exported file.

Comment: iOS uses Y_UP... Blender will just have to support it shortly.